# How to query from geojson object?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, postgis

In the below posted query I want to query the following information

```sql
    ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
```

The `featuresCollection` is a geojson object.

How can I query from a geojson object?

```sql
    query="""   
            WITH data AS (
                SELECT '{featuresCollection}'::json AS featuresCollection
            )
            SELECT 
                LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry,
            FROM (
                SELECT 
                    ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
                
            FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature 
                    FROM data) AS f) j
            GROUP BY LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
        """.format(table=config['PostgreDB']['table_name_test'], width=config['Grid']['cell_width'], height=config['Grid']['cell_height'],bufferRadius=config['Grid']['buffer_radius'],featuresCollection=featuresCollection)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just unpack your feature collection in a subquery, extract the geometries and apply the transformation you want, e.g. from a table called `t` with a column `geojson` containing GeoJSON strings:

```
SELECT 
 ST_Transform(
  ST_SetSRID(
    ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832)  
FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(geojson->'features') AS feature FROM t) data;
```

Comment: would you please answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757059/query-st-intersection-can-not-be-executed