# How to use ST_Intersects in WHERE clause

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

i would like to know how to perform the following operation

```
WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(dataSource.LIDARDataAsSinglePolygon,geom)
```

**query**:

```
  def exec(self,geometryAsGeoJSONObjectAsString,geom):
    query="""
    WITH dataSource As(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'))) As LIDARDataAsSinglePolygonUsingST_UnionAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326,
        ST_AsText(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'))) As LIDARDataAsSinglePolygon
        )
    FROM 
        (SELECT json_array_elements('{geometryAsGeoJSONObjectAsString}'::json->'features') AS feature) a WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(dataSource.LIDARDataAsSinglePolygon,geom);
    """.format(geometryAsGeoJSONObjectAsString=geometryAsGeoJSONObjectAsString)
    print(query)
    data = self.connection.query(query,[])
    # print(data)        
    return data
```

**fiddle**:

```
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8dc0ccc1017a220098022131e8d41063
```

Comment: what is the role of table `s_30m_test` in your fiddle - it is not mentioned anywhere in the query? Can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JimJones i dont know why the s_30m_test appears.it is only the last query the one with dataSource..is it clear now

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely trying to use `ST_Intersects` with an alias of an expression, not a column or a geometry. And you're logic is inverted: you need to first parse and dump the geometries from your feature collection and then apply the filter, not the other way around:

```
WITH datasource (feature) AS (
 SELECT json_array_elements('{json_string}'::json->'features')  
)
SELECT 
  ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'))),
  ST_AsText(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry')))
FROM datasource
WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),'{a geometry}');
```

Comment: would you please add whatever related to how to iterate through all the points of geometry? i mean for freature->>'geometry' it contains point,right? i would like to be able to apply spacial operation on these points....would you please add it

Comment: @LetsamrIt you mean the elements of the json string are points? If so, the outer query will iterate over them and check if they intersect (perhaps contains would be a better choice) with a given polygon.

Comment: would you please add that as a separate code.. i mean i want the code displayed now and for the code of the 'contain' would please added separately!!

Comment: the idea is that some of the feature->>geometry intersects with {a geometry} i want to get rid of the intersected part only not to exclude the entire feature->>geometry..is it clearer now?

Comment: @LetsamrIt You mean this `WHERE NOT ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),'{a geometry}');`?

Comment: but in this case if portion of feature->>geometry intersects with {a geometry} the entire feature->>geometry will not be considered. i would like to get rid of the intersected part only, is it possible

Comment: @LetsamrIt can you give me an example of a geometry and the result you expect? If you put a `NOT` before interesect, the query will return all features that do not intersect with the polygon, which is what you want. You can also try `ST_Disjoint(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),'{a geometry}'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235967/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-letsamrit).