# How to filter postgis queries based on ST_GeometryType

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i have the below posted query. and i would like to add in the where clause the following

```
AND ST_GeometryType(geom.dump) LIKE "ST_Multipolygon"
```

i would like to filter out the geometries of type multipolgon
please let me know how can i do that

**query**

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
        ST_X(ST_Dump((ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(
                ST_SetSRID(
                    ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),
                    25832),ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))'),4326),25832)),4326))).geom))  As dump --here this geomtry can be replaced by multipolgon for testing

        FROM slope inner join  (select
                st_setsrid(st_transform(st_setsrid(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))'),4326),25832), 30),25832),31467),25832) as geom
                ) a  on point && a.geom
        JOIN (
            WITH data AS (
            SELECT '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69253798665417, 51.1321564140328], [6.69251962171524, 51.1321635163992], [6.69249846231729, 51.1321750605202], [6.69249925136169, 51.1321793032012], [6.69251085641084, 51.1321902349559], [6.6925202281672, 51.1321886211859], [6.6925350953045, 51.13217713273], [6.69253798665417, 51.1321564140328]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "2"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69269313266862, 51.1321811516334], [6.69269456345932, 51.1321667897304], [6.69269648476695, 51.1321311221074], [6.69269663315549, 51.1321252790401], [6.69269334643976, 51.132113791988], [6.69268514848039, 51.1321147993719], [6.69266813655301, 51.1321177013629], [6.69265269992705, 51.1321205445076], [6.69260400160369, 51.1321339733957], [6.69259342024285, 51.1321369123716], [6.69257235999851, 51.1321436017891], [6.6925532535978, 51.1321770414777], [6.69254076871528, 51.1322152886675], [6.69253704911869, 51.1322268172979], [6.69253585685355, 51.1322306611143], [6.69253560204644, 51.1322329045446], [6.69253742373699, 51.132250838247], [6.69255296008214, 51.1322631966762], [6.69261518281268, 51.1322824125944], [6.69263790187194, 51.1322825912308], [6.69264662627284, 51.1322824936254], [6.69267258657931, 51.132229132945], [6.69269313266862, 51.1321811516334]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "3"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69251672749726, 51.1322215594779], [6.69250460947264, 51.1322094483985], [6.6924921739216, 51.1322008386475], [6.69248182942694, 51.1322018935827], [6.69246834157673, 51.132211520553], [6.69244929502299, 51.1322351581201], [6.69245199419083, 51.1322612935409], [6.69246425167291, 51.1322677412591], [6.69248454251289, 51.1322707500203], [6.69250080856706, 51.1322713409299], [6.69251741124046, 51.1322393807793], [6.69251672749726, 51.1322215594779]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "4"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.6922825274399, 51.1323259414957], [6.69227206035333, 51.1323151221225], [6.69224485573949, 51.1322959677944], [6.69223824707324, 51.1322937687407], [6.69222068683045, 51.1322933321209], [6.69221819197358, 51.1322946319424], [6.69218894528929, 51.1323106931418], [6.69217475443148, 51.1323315485006], [6.69217341036882, 51.1323355691933], [6.69217231313262, 51.1323547044118], [6.69217324495241, 51.1323589499138], [6.69217569889977, 51.1323613367604], [6.69218142835096, 51.1323639681514], [6.6922037172841, 51.1323727724673], [6.69223780236341, 51.1323743447748], [6.69226136483905, 51.1323748099503], [6.69226799202122, 51.1323737715855], [6.69228555129034, 51.1323570299429], [6.69228519515222, 51.1323527058685], [6.6922825274399, 51.1323259414957]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "5"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69270036788524, 51.1326380915836], [6.69270044963208, 51.1326307182485], [6.69269979440667, 51.1326266580875], [6.69265572460697, 51.1326103188106], [6.69258556546035, 51.1325983212077], [6.69257773814301, 51.1325976270713], [6.69257545328535, 51.1325975819696], [6.69254710479826, 51.1326070954851], [6.69254041373701, 51.1326151478002], [6.69256693935704, 51.1326393252039], [6.69259572746481, 51.1326639969531], [6.69261808158644, 51.1326829655137], [6.69263440827555, 51.1326938105779], [6.69266740157087, 51.1326886158279], [6.69268164386179, 51.1326781942805], [6.6926927410912, 51.1326620445339], [6.69269711646734, 51.1326516980425], [6.69270036788524, 51.1326380915836]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "6"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69175796394166, 51.1325888173132], [6.69180793429611, 51.1324725243485], [6.69180892473724, 51.1324526675166], [6.69180413787601, 51.1324454678607], [6.6917982202076, 51.1324466101479], [6.69178087259056, 51.1324533727339], [6.69171031275604, 51.1324809395917], [6.69167093571617, 51.1324966207435], [6.69162081516962, 51.132521353381], [6.69161040721569, 51.1325265441535], [6.69161011264506, 51.1325267182132], [6.69159802180106, 51.1325341242118], [6.69157656681147, 51.1325487202367], [6.69155258043593, 51.1325682128804], [6.69153973458902, 51.1325792914381], [6.69150389109257, 51.1326186961186], [6.69147684379341, 51.1326766219394], [6.69147001176052, 51.1327161498552], [6.6914699304478, 51.1327206451701], [6.69147004831695, 51.1327326093068], [6.69147598409746, 51.1327712201722], [6.69149221971477, 51.1328096746915], [6.69150093658731, 51.1328240571066], [6.69151196908048, 51.1328407337113], [6.69152518846839, 51.1328565541182], [6.69154021053508, 51.1328734893842], [6.69155054373049, 51.1328841263015], [6.69158606889102, 51.132914147773], [6.69159074495821, 51.1329178376514], [6.69159617152892, 51.132917944814], [6.69160772711436, 51.132909808738], [6.69163093798561, 51.132865747583], [6.69164647462266, 51.1328351155779], [6.69171060598049, 51.1326957183096], [6.69175796394166, 51.1325888173132]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "7"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69280944347454, 51.1327325212954], [6.69278198469405, 51.1327098544827], [6.69276787507997, 51.1327032803041], [6.69275702253061, 51.1327001880702], [6.6927110654878, 51.1327274316875], [6.69270049184791, 51.1327359470067], [6.69269795107157, 51.1327439013734], [6.69269675432507, 51.1327478350411], [6.69269555757836, 51.1327517687087], [6.69270108943557, 51.1327612314915], [6.69272374606894, 51.1327856023059], [6.69273137237766, 51.132787461664], [6.69274887457694, 51.1327890662591], [6.69278274605442, 51.1327891951749], [6.69279197959956, 51.1327874887162], [6.69280546252786, 51.1327808295785], [6.69281911568176, 51.13277075614], [6.692818514201, 51.1327656177799], [6.69280944347454, 51.1327325212954]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "8"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69300203804217, 51.1328749175082], [6.69298489450558, 51.1328403126402], [6.69297071368933, 51.1328322980672], [6.69294514042643, 51.1328205510521], [6.69289902806839, 51.1328193711454], [6.69286658297828, 51.1328279045017], [6.69286227033698, 51.1328369930997], [6.6928613985622, 51.1328688140847], [6.69286281220306, 51.132897802148], [6.69287913508867, 51.1329058590115], [6.6928817901407, 51.1329070806127], [6.69290110745025, 51.1329152865115], [6.69291370059255, 51.1329178734543], [6.69292154588787, 51.1329182081691], [6.69294384634694, 51.1329153205768], [6.69297262282259, 51.13290869344], [6.69298582911113, 51.132901848945], [6.69300203804217, 51.1328749175082]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "9"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69232916938592, 51.133110495585], [6.69233421078188, 51.1330953955202], [6.69235075084229, 51.1330217027418], [6.69235005039201, 51.1329984848074], [6.69233579852696, 51.1329890297401], [6.69215882485022, 51.1329777112594], [6.69215447738489, 51.1329817625941], [6.69209733560649, 51.1330555531216], [6.69209320085406, 51.1330668037259], [6.6920424322757, 51.1332449586609], [6.69204425051294, 51.1332572261821], [6.69204991732763, 51.1332611154794], [6.69208256036642, 51.1332686852289], [6.69214233141891, 51.1332797585278], [6.69218590448418, 51.1332831370578], [6.69223609649279, 51.133282778893], [6.69232916938592, 51.133110495585]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "10"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69309575564949, 51.1329620286457], [6.69309963642392, 51.1329472653982], [6.69309881754873, 51.132935017617], [6.69307203062263, 51.1329218076648], [6.69305328289965, 51.1329222471207], [6.6930360925896, 51.1329229871251], [6.69303076850343, 51.1329236914975], [6.69298880311273, 51.1329396817633], [6.69297592220055, 51.1329486012633], [6.69296986419304, 51.1329840973053], [6.69297042430155, 51.1329958003503], [6.69297292705951, 51.1330000768489], [6.69301308177035, 51.1330261420197], [6.69301918206967, 51.133027071858], [6.69303825522546, 51.1330287074127], [6.69306059103336, 51.1330279790168], [6.69307287545165, 51.1330109532808], [6.69307979887065, 51.1330011067537], [6.69308523205943, 51.1329896119255], [6.69309575564949, 51.1329620286457]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "11"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69264305397923, 51.1322939352281], [6.69264424175731, 51.1322901812605], [6.69264543849516, 51.132286247593], [6.69263785259199, 51.1322835795805], [6.69252746167717, 51.1322814904708], [6.6925183127842, 51.1322843677784], [6.69250842691038, 51.1322905582583], [6.69250503044308, 51.1322927396721], [6.69250412882457, 51.1322936212581], [6.69250834622358, 51.1323151098501], [6.6925161404358, 51.1323250669937], [6.69254901931236, 51.1323359689943], [6.69251034598528, 51.1323352055896], [6.69249005454883, 51.1323350748503], [6.69245693248874, 51.1324059220424], [6.69245559292849, 51.1324098528887], [6.6924544006514, 51.132413696704], [6.69247323550652, 51.1324229724131], [6.69251602483015, 51.132428196049], [6.69246937307172, 51.1324344982216], [6.69244175489256, 51.1324523004608], [6.69244041532956, 51.1324562313069], [6.6924378700452, 51.1324642755178], [6.69243748586974, 51.1324662465788], [6.69244000419296, 51.132481675759], [6.69244043552284, 51.1324828388153], [6.69242276418403, 51.1324862820424], [6.69242216608837, 51.1324868098659], [6.69240793104538, 51.132505685735], [6.69240683952442, 51.1325189750712], [6.69240749472285, 51.1325230352335], [6.69245266197307, 51.1325402956537], [6.69246074152444, 51.1325404449095], [6.69245904780327, 51.1325412311583], [6.69246089414942, 51.1325472035405], [6.69248390393314, 51.1325673542701], [6.69249665598157, 51.1325782187286], [6.692498177537, 51.1325792380866], [6.69250207298905, 51.1325813835662], [6.69250992213802, 51.1325845064756], [6.69251385399889, 51.1325830551374], [6.69253035818111, 51.1325760059787], [6.69253149503538, 51.1325589401237], [6.69253220875509, 51.1325413559783], [6.69254382431863, 51.1325410159433], [6.69256431636541, 51.1324969908775], [6.69256499007752, 51.1324748793294], [6.69255810773198, 51.132470462385], [6.69257536992313, 51.1324530493135], [6.69257749741779, 51.1324361828893], [6.69257444491701, 51.132435038046], [6.69258994872926, 51.1324330110108], [6.69259606294197, 51.1324307933024], [6.69262641162471, 51.132346760322], [6.69262231830842, 51.1323440804244], [6.69262697891405, 51.1323439834292], [6.69264305397923, 51.1322939352281]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "12"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69242704496132, 51.132323038405], [6.69242269090442, 51.1323157573803], [6.692417553916, 51.1323184440628], [6.69241644391112, 51.1323349708171], [6.69242163295421, 51.1323398399883], [6.69242452621548, 51.1323414919739], [6.6923997028096, 51.1323668382825], [6.69237476252063, 51.1324054691417], [6.69237385584298, 51.1324093185943], [6.6923741412481, 51.1324098621282], [6.69236742132112, 51.1324064934171], [6.69230798969311, 51.1323771694288], [6.69230617358135, 51.13237632413], [6.69228802417196, 51.132376235643], [6.69228559204211, 51.1323762775666], [6.69224488018429, 51.1323957999097], [6.6922422099899, 51.1324034818971], [6.69224101769533, 51.13240732571], [6.69224077631505, 51.1324092995895], [6.69223922596153, 51.1324403876708], [6.69234968554863, 51.1325471667089], [6.69237904767688, 51.1325345254075], [6.69238858528683, 51.1325295872009], [6.69241875730355, 51.1324835047915], [6.692423113175, 51.1324592174721], [6.69242348057106, 51.1324518497756], [6.69242282089158, 51.1324478794633], [6.69242216121221, 51.132443909151], [6.69242027569293, 51.1324329893825], [6.69241230485538, 51.1324289935948], [6.69243827735106, 51.1324131086063], [6.69245242722499, 51.132395939882], [6.69245495010085, 51.1323883449204], [6.69247131545421, 51.1323382125338], [6.69247250772775, 51.1323343687182], [6.69246979340118, 51.1323171369011], [6.69246938291431, 51.1323167690444], [6.69244774801696, 51.1323177809765], [6.69242811022654, 51.132337832463], [6.69242940760109, 51.1323358562987], [6.69242910521451, 51.1323304540251], [6.69242704496132, 51.132323038405]]]}}]}'::json AS featuresCollection
            )
            SELECT
            LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
            
            FROM (
            SELECT
                ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry

            FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature
                    FROM data) AS f) j
            GROUP BY
            LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
            ) j ON


            NOT ST_Contains('0103000020E864000001000000070000002CC1936439AA1441C2E17F35419E554194D77D6744A91441B8177F714B9E554159A47F43A1A914411A88C850539E5541FCEF81F020AA1441326CDC41509E5541EBFA8E0417AA14415F982DA94A9E554157E297C4D6A91441686B6D77459E55412CC1936439AA1441C2E17F35419E5541',ST_Centroid(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),25832)))
            AND
                ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))'),4326),25832), ST_Centroid(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEnvelope(
                ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),25832)))
```

Comment: Can you please add the create table and insert statements for the related data in a fiddle?

Comment: @JimJones i tried but could not do it successfully:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=70600e37cc517019a555a2cd8cdb4275

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fairly large and due to the lack of indentation and a working fiddle it is hard to know where the problem is. For further questions consider creating a [`minimal reproducible example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I also noticed that in a single query you're transforming geometries 18 times (!) back and forth between `31467` and `25832`. Is it really necessary? Keep in mind that transformations might take time and will certainly slow down your queries. Make the necessary transformations, if possible, in the origin or in the end of a chain of functions. For instance, instead of

```
WITH j (point) AS(
  VALUES ('POINT(1 2)'::geometry)
)  
SELECT st_astext(
ST_MakeEnvelope(
  ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
  ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
  ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
  ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),2)
FROM j;
```

.. consider this:

```
WITH j (point) AS(
  VALUES (ST_SetSRID('POINT(1 2)'::geometry,31467))
)  
SELECT 
 ST_Transform(    
   ST_MakeEnvelope(
     ST_X(point),ST_Y(point),ST_X(point)+10,ST_Y(point)+10,31467),
  25832)
FROM j
```

The results might be slightly different, but depending on your use case it won't matter much. Try both approaches and if possible keep your code clean.

That being said, you could use `ST_NumGeometries` to count the number of geometries in a column:

```
SELECT 
  ST_NumGeometries('MULTIPOLYGON (((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40)),((20 35, 10 30, 10 10, 30 5, 45 20, 20 35)))'::geometry),
  ST_NumGeometries('POLYGON((40 40, 20 45, 45 30, 40 40))'::geometry);

 st_numgeometries | st_numgeometries 
------------------+------------------
                2 |                1
```

So your query should look like this:

```
WITH j AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT
           ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10) AS geom_int1,
           ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))')  AS geom_int2 
           FROM slope inner join  (select
                    st_setsrid(st_transform(st_setsrid(ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))'),4326),25832), 30),25832),31467),25832) as geom
                    ) a  on point && a.geom
            JOIN (
                WITH data AS (
                SELECT '{"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "1"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69253798665417, 51.1321564140328], [6.69251962171524, 51.1321635163992], [6.69249846231729, 51.1321750605202], [6.69249925136169, 51.1321793032012], [6.69251085641084, 51.1321902349559], [6.6925202281672, 51.1321886211859], [6.6925350953045, 51.13217713273], [6.69253798665417, 51.1321564140328]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "2"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69269313266862, 51.1321811516334], [6.69269456345932, 51.1321667897304], [6.69269648476695, 51.1321311221074], [6.69269663315549, 51.1321252790401], [6.69269334643976, 51.132113791988], [6.69268514848039, 51.1321147993719], [6.69266813655301, 51.1321177013629], [6.69265269992705, 51.1321205445076], [6.69260400160369, 51.1321339733957], [6.69259342024285, 51.1321369123716], [6.69257235999851, 51.1321436017891], [6.6925532535978, 51.1321770414777], [6.69254076871528, 51.1322152886675], [6.69253704911869, 51.1322268172979], [6.69253585685355, 51.1322306611143], [6.69253560204644, 51.1322329045446], [6.69253742373699, 51.132250838247], [6.69255296008214, 51.1322631966762], [6.69261518281268, 51.1322824125944], [6.69263790187194, 51.1322825912308], [6.69264662627284, 51.1322824936254], [6.69267258657931, 51.132229132945], [6.69269313266862, 51.1321811516334]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "3"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69251672749726, 51.1322215594779], [6.69250460947264, 51.1322094483985], [6.6924921739216, 51.1322008386475], [6.69248182942694, 51.1322018935827], [6.69246834157673, 51.132211520553], [6.69244929502299, 51.1322351581201], [6.69245199419083, 51.1322612935409], [6.69246425167291, 51.1322677412591], [6.69248454251289, 51.1322707500203], [6.69250080856706, 51.1322713409299], [6.69251741124046, 51.1322393807793], [6.69251672749726, 51.1322215594779]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "4"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.6922825274399, 51.1323259414957], [6.69227206035333, 51.1323151221225], [6.69224485573949, 51.1322959677944], [6.69223824707324, 51.1322937687407], [6.69222068683045, 51.1322933321209], [6.69221819197358, 51.1322946319424], [6.69218894528929, 51.1323106931418], [6.69217475443148, 51.1323315485006], [6.69217341036882, 51.1323355691933], [6.69217231313262, 51.1323547044118], [6.69217324495241, 51.1323589499138], [6.69217569889977, 51.1323613367604], [6.69218142835096, 51.1323639681514], [6.6922037172841, 51.1323727724673], [6.69223780236341, 51.1323743447748], [6.69226136483905, 51.1323748099503], [6.69226799202122, 51.1323737715855], [6.69228555129034, 51.1323570299429], [6.69228519515222, 51.1323527058685], [6.6922825274399, 51.1323259414957]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "5"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69270036788524, 51.1326380915836], [6.69270044963208, 51.1326307182485], [6.69269979440667, 51.1326266580875], [6.69265572460697, 51.1326103188106], [6.69258556546035, 51.1325983212077], [6.69257773814301, 51.1325976270713], [6.69257545328535, 51.1325975819696], [6.69254710479826, 51.1326070954851], [6.69254041373701, 51.1326151478002], [6.69256693935704, 51.1326393252039], [6.69259572746481, 51.1326639969531], [6.69261808158644, 51.1326829655137], [6.69263440827555, 51.1326938105779], [6.69266740157087, 51.1326886158279], [6.69268164386179, 51.1326781942805], [6.6926927410912, 51.1326620445339], [6.69269711646734, 51.1326516980425], [6.69270036788524, 51.1326380915836]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "6"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69175796394166, 51.1325888173132], [6.69180793429611, 51.1324725243485], [6.69180892473724, 51.1324526675166], [6.69180413787601, 51.1324454678607], [6.6917982202076, 51.1324466101479], [6.69178087259056, 51.1324533727339], [6.69171031275604, 51.1324809395917], [6.69167093571617, 51.1324966207435], [6.69162081516962, 51.132521353381], [6.69161040721569, 51.1325265441535], [6.69161011264506, 51.1325267182132], [6.69159802180106, 51.1325341242118], [6.69157656681147, 51.1325487202367], [6.69155258043593, 51.1325682128804], [6.69153973458902, 51.1325792914381], [6.69150389109257, 51.1326186961186], [6.69147684379341, 51.1326766219394], [6.69147001176052, 51.1327161498552], [6.6914699304478, 51.1327206451701], [6.69147004831695, 51.1327326093068], [6.69147598409746, 51.1327712201722], [6.69149221971477, 51.1328096746915], [6.69150093658731, 51.1328240571066], [6.69151196908048, 51.1328407337113], [6.69152518846839, 51.1328565541182], [6.69154021053508, 51.1328734893842], [6.69155054373049, 51.1328841263015], [6.69158606889102, 51.132914147773], [6.69159074495821, 51.1329178376514], [6.69159617152892, 51.132917944814], [6.69160772711436, 51.132909808738], [6.69163093798561, 51.132865747583], [6.69164647462266, 51.1328351155779], [6.69171060598049, 51.1326957183096], [6.69175796394166, 51.1325888173132]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "7"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69280944347454, 51.1327325212954], [6.69278198469405, 51.1327098544827], [6.69276787507997, 51.1327032803041], [6.69275702253061, 51.1327001880702], [6.6927110654878, 51.1327274316875], [6.69270049184791, 51.1327359470067], [6.69269795107157, 51.1327439013734], [6.69269675432507, 51.1327478350411], [6.69269555757836, 51.1327517687087], [6.69270108943557, 51.1327612314915], [6.69272374606894, 51.1327856023059], [6.69273137237766, 51.132787461664], [6.69274887457694, 51.1327890662591], [6.69278274605442, 51.1327891951749], [6.69279197959956, 51.1327874887162], [6.69280546252786, 51.1327808295785], [6.69281911568176, 51.13277075614], [6.692818514201, 51.1327656177799], [6.69280944347454, 51.1327325212954]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "8"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69300203804217, 51.1328749175082], [6.69298489450558, 51.1328403126402], [6.69297071368933, 51.1328322980672], [6.69294514042643, 51.1328205510521], [6.69289902806839, 51.1328193711454], [6.69286658297828, 51.1328279045017], [6.69286227033698, 51.1328369930997], [6.6928613985622, 51.1328688140847], [6.69286281220306, 51.132897802148], [6.69287913508867, 51.1329058590115], [6.6928817901407, 51.1329070806127], [6.69290110745025, 51.1329152865115], [6.69291370059255, 51.1329178734543], [6.69292154588787, 51.1329182081691], [6.69294384634694, 51.1329153205768], [6.69297262282259, 51.13290869344], [6.69298582911113, 51.132901848945], [6.69300203804217, 51.1328749175082]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "9"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69232916938592, 51.133110495585], [6.69233421078188, 51.1330953955202], [6.69235075084229, 51.1330217027418], [6.69235005039201, 51.1329984848074], [6.69233579852696, 51.1329890297401], [6.69215882485022, 51.1329777112594], [6.69215447738489, 51.1329817625941], [6.69209733560649, 51.1330555531216], [6.69209320085406, 51.1330668037259], [6.6920424322757, 51.1332449586609], [6.69204425051294, 51.1332572261821], [6.69204991732763, 51.1332611154794], [6.69208256036642, 51.1332686852289], [6.69214233141891, 51.1332797585278], [6.69218590448418, 51.1332831370578], [6.69223609649279, 51.133282778893], [6.69232916938592, 51.133110495585]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "10"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69309575564949, 51.1329620286457], [6.69309963642392, 51.1329472653982], [6.69309881754873, 51.132935017617], [6.69307203062263, 51.1329218076648], [6.69305328289965, 51.1329222471207], [6.6930360925896, 51.1329229871251], [6.69303076850343, 51.1329236914975], [6.69298880311273, 51.1329396817633], [6.69297592220055, 51.1329486012633], [6.69296986419304, 51.1329840973053], [6.69297042430155, 51.1329958003503], [6.69297292705951, 51.1330000768489], [6.69301308177035, 51.1330261420197], [6.69301918206967, 51.133027071858], [6.69303825522546, 51.1330287074127], [6.69306059103336, 51.1330279790168], [6.69307287545165, 51.1330109532808], [6.69307979887065, 51.1330011067537], [6.69308523205943, 51.1329896119255], [6.69309575564949, 51.1329620286457]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "11"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69264305397923, 51.1322939352281], [6.69264424175731, 51.1322901812605], [6.69264543849516, 51.132286247593], [6.69263785259199, 51.1322835795805], [6.69252746167717, 51.1322814904708], [6.6925183127842, 51.1322843677784], [6.69250842691038, 51.1322905582583], [6.69250503044308, 51.1322927396721], [6.69250412882457, 51.1322936212581], [6.69250834622358, 51.1323151098501], [6.6925161404358, 51.1323250669937], [6.69254901931236, 51.1323359689943], [6.69251034598528, 51.1323352055896], [6.69249005454883, 51.1323350748503], [6.69245693248874, 51.1324059220424], [6.69245559292849, 51.1324098528887], [6.6924544006514, 51.132413696704], [6.69247323550652, 51.1324229724131], [6.69251602483015, 51.132428196049], [6.69246937307172, 51.1324344982216], [6.69244175489256, 51.1324523004608], [6.69244041532956, 51.1324562313069], [6.6924378700452, 51.1324642755178], [6.69243748586974, 51.1324662465788], [6.69244000419296, 51.132481675759], [6.69244043552284, 51.1324828388153], [6.69242276418403, 51.1324862820424], [6.69242216608837, 51.1324868098659], [6.69240793104538, 51.132505685735], [6.69240683952442, 51.1325189750712], [6.69240749472285, 51.1325230352335], [6.69245266197307, 51.1325402956537], [6.69246074152444, 51.1325404449095], [6.69245904780327, 51.1325412311583], [6.69246089414942, 51.1325472035405], [6.69248390393314, 51.1325673542701], [6.69249665598157, 51.1325782187286], [6.692498177537, 51.1325792380866], [6.69250207298905, 51.1325813835662], [6.69250992213802, 51.1325845064756], [6.69251385399889, 51.1325830551374], [6.69253035818111, 51.1325760059787], [6.69253149503538, 51.1325589401237], [6.69253220875509, 51.1325413559783], [6.69254382431863, 51.1325410159433], [6.69256431636541, 51.1324969908775], [6.69256499007752, 51.1324748793294], [6.69255810773198, 51.132470462385], [6.69257536992313, 51.1324530493135], [6.69257749741779, 51.1324361828893], [6.69257444491701, 51.132435038046], [6.69258994872926, 51.1324330110108], [6.69259606294197, 51.1324307933024], [6.69262641162471, 51.132346760322], [6.69262231830842, 51.1323440804244], [6.69262697891405, 51.1323439834292], [6.69264305397923, 51.1322939352281]]]}}, {"type": "Feature", "properties": {"ID": "12"}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[6.69242704496132, 51.132323038405], [6.69242269090442, 51.1323157573803], [6.692417553916, 51.1323184440628], [6.69241644391112, 51.1323349708171], [6.69242163295421, 51.1323398399883], [6.69242452621548, 51.1323414919739], [6.6923997028096, 51.1323668382825], [6.69237476252063, 51.1324054691417], [6.69237385584298, 51.1324093185943], [6.6923741412481, 51.1324098621282], [6.69236742132112, 51.1324064934171], [6.69230798969311, 51.1323771694288], [6.69230617358135, 51.13237632413], [6.69228802417196, 51.132376235643], [6.69228559204211, 51.1323762775666], [6.69224488018429, 51.1323957999097], [6.6922422099899, 51.1324034818971], [6.69224101769533, 51.13240732571], [6.69224077631505, 51.1324092995895], [6.69223922596153, 51.1324403876708], [6.69234968554863, 51.1325471667089], [6.69237904767688, 51.1325345254075], [6.69238858528683, 51.1325295872009], [6.69241875730355, 51.1324835047915], [6.692423113175, 51.1324592174721], [6.69242348057106, 51.1324518497756], [6.69242282089158, 51.1324478794633], [6.69242216121221, 51.132443909151], [6.69242027569293, 51.1324329893825], [6.69241230485538, 51.1324289935948], [6.69243827735106, 51.1324131086063], [6.69245242722499, 51.132395939882], [6.69245495010085, 51.1323883449204], [6.69247131545421, 51.1323382125338], [6.69247250772775, 51.1323343687182], [6.69246979340118, 51.1323171369011], [6.69246938291431, 51.1323167690444], [6.69244774801696, 51.1323177809765], [6.69242811022654, 51.132337832463], [6.69242940760109, 51.1323358562987], [6.69242910521451, 51.1323304540251], [6.69242704496132, 51.132323038405]]]}}]}'::json AS featuresCollection
                )
                SELECT
                LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
                
                FROM (
                SELECT
                    ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feature->>'geometry'),4326),25832) AS LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry

                FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(featuresCollection->'features') AS feature
                        FROM data) AS f) j
                GROUP BY
                LIDARDataPolygonsAsGeometry
                ) j ON
    

                NOT ST_Contains('0103000020E864000001000000070000002CC1936439AA1441C2E17F35419E554194D77D6744A91441B8177F714B9E554159A47F43A1A914411A88C850539E5541FCEF81F020AA1441326CDC41509E5541EBFA8E0417AA14415F982DA94A9E554157E297C4D6A91441686B6D77459E55412CC1936439AA1441C2E17F35419E5541',ST_Centroid(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),25832)))
                AND
                    ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078,6.69314216094032 51.1325286743429,6.6931829229236 51.1324827378523,6.69320873406544 51.1324326960125,6.69321861208315 51.1323804533377,6.69321218108977 51.1323279980963,6.69318968589172 51.1322773266396,6.69315198266368 51.1322303674254,6.69310050635699 51.1321889076246,6.69303721608294 51.1321545251075,6.69296452055024 51.1321285283945,6.69288518639497 51.1321119068596,6.6928022328913 51.132105293078,6.69271881704983 51.1321089387537,6.69263811347528 51.1321227051402,6.69256319355485 51.1321460683214,6.69167022350287 51.1324966230214,6.691601844655 51.1325299362666,6.69154548586769 51.1325712077134,6.6915034414949 51.1326187572348,6.69147742317882 51.1326706491231,6.69146849016453 51.1327247708897,6.69147700617074 51.1327789192613,6.69150262457336 51.1328308898743,6.69154430250688 51.1328785670135,6.6918617087031 51.1331680405352,6.69191278478678 51.1332064363834,6.69197426178939 51.1332382298226,6.69204402058778 51.1332623249167,6.69211965656854 51.1332778910942,6.69219856251863 51.133284391779,6.6922780185011 51.1332816028878,6.69235528561775 51.1332696205548,6.69281658666282 51.13316870319,6.69288972627184 51.1331476779976,6.6929553372192 51.1331184277034,6.6930111102981 51.1330819817912,6.69305508256535 51.1330396229968,6.69308570642734 51.1329928421602,6.69310190410533 51.1329432857531,6.69310310556331 51.1328926979291,6.69307771111191 51.1326908636516,6.69306446700159 51.1326424034468,6.69303745832752 51.1325962617897,6.69303600327017 51.1325947186521,6.69308799941667 51.1325687572078),(6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628,6.69265042517401 51.1327121450621,6.6926758177672 51.132913979408,6.69221451899067 51.13301489625,6.69189711157563 51.1327254236646,6.69279008443662 51.1323748672786,6.69243035603289 51.1325209327628))'),4326),25832), ST_Centroid(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeEnvelope(
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832)),
                    ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10,
                    ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(point,31467),25832))+10),25832)))

)
SELECT * 
FROM j
WHERE 
  ST_NumGeometries(
    ST_Intersection(geom_int1,geom_int2)) > 1
```

Comment: i will study your query and of couers acknowlege

Comment: would you please check this question?it is about data-binding in postgresql:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68933952/how-to-add-a-geometry-as-a-binding-variable

Comment: can you tell me please why this geojson is invalied:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69188363/how-to-validate-properties-key-in-a-geojson

Comment: hi, would like to solve this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69720628/how-to-specify-table-name-using-s

Comment: @LetsamrIt it seems your question was closed before we could do anything :)

Comment: yes,unfortunately..could you please provide some hints to solve this issue

Comment: Hi, would you please have alook at this one before it get closed :) :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69734172/how-to-specify-a-column-of-type-geometry

Comment: hi, i have a question please. i have an array of polygons as features. is it possible to build featurecollection out of it in postgis?

Comment: @LetsamrIt yes, it is possible with `ST_Union`.

Comment: but st_union returns geometry not a featureCollection!!

Comment: @LetsamrIt Now I get what you want, a GeoJson featurecollection. Yes, it is possible with json aggregate functions. I might have a script somewhere, but to be sure it is best if you post a question and we delete this conversation here, otherwise nobody will ever read it. cheers

Comment: would you like to answer this question please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69899175/how-to-insert-value-to-a-column-as-a-result-of-geometry-of-another-column-in-the

Comment: @LetsamrIt did you post the question with the arrays?

Comment: which question??

Comment: @LetsamrIt nevermind, I thought you would post a question on how to transform an array of polygons into a feature collection. Cheers