# how to validate properties key in a geojson

Tags: python, json, postgis, geojson

i would like to know why the below posted geojson format is invalid. i tried to visualize its data in
http://geojson.io

but nothing gets displayed.

**geojson**

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[[7.85563468082516,49.90287230375267],[7.855636808249913,49.902782379662085],[7.855776033932631,49.902783753651605],[7.855773906766568,49.902873677746555]]
]
]
},"properties": {"areaOfCoverage":"30"}},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "properties":{"areaOfCoverage":"30"},
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
               7.85563468082516,
              49.90287230375267
            ],
            [
              7.855636808249913,
              49.902782379662085
            ],
            [
              7.855776033932631,
              49.902783753651605
            ],
            [
              7.85563468082516,
              49.90287230375267
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i tried itand followed the structure you provided but nothing is displayed. would you please use the same coordinates:{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "areaOfCoverage": "30"
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [7.85563468082516,49.90287230375267],
            [7.855636808249913,49.902782379662085],
            [7.855776033932631,49.902783753651605],
            [7.855773906766568,49.902873677746555]
          ]
  ]    }
   }
  ]
}

Comment: Your first and last coorinates must be same.