# How to specify a columns for a Copy From query

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

in the below code, i want to create a copy-from. for the parameter `str` it contains geomeries of `POINT` in epsg25832. i want to populate the column `pointGeometry` with the values from `str`.For the column `distanceToNearestEdge` it must contain calculated distance
from the the points in `pointGeometry` to a particular polygon.

at run time, i get error says:

```
    psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »geometry«
    LINE 3:                 pointGeometry geometry(point,25832),
```

1-please let me know how to specify a column of type geometry
2-after solving the issue in the previous point, how to populate the column `distanceToNearestEdge` with the value of the distance from the point to a particular polygon

**sample points**:
the variable str contains the following:

```
POINT (5630506.13939328 996474.635561104)
POINT (5630504.31893951 996495.786819386)
POINT (5630492.79190135 996473.890690898)
POINT (5630490.97145872 996495.04187886)
POINT (5630479.44442823 996473.145821843)
POINT (5630477.62399676 996494.296939486)
POINT (5630475.80349211 996515.448049693)
POINT (5630464.27655362 996493.552001265)
POINT (5630462.45606011 996514.703041153)
POINT (5630455.17335431 996599.307126336)
POINT (5630453.35249492 996620.458129037)
POINT (5630460.03044341 996387.052104826)
POINT (5630458.21032694 996408.203111568)
POINT (5630450.9291293 996492.807064196)
POINT (5630449.10864695 996513.958033765)
POINT (5630443.64676082 996577.410897854)
POINT (5630441.82598575 996598.561837676)
POINT (5630440.00513751 996619.712770058)
POINT (5630446.68298218 996386.307520502)
POINT (5630444.86287686 996407.458456925)
POINT (5630437.58172381 996492.062128279)
POINT (5630435.76125261 996513.21302753)
POINT (5630432.12009066 996555.514803724)
POINT (5630430.29939992 996576.665680666)
POINT (5630428.47863601 996597.816550169)
POINT (5630433.33553977 996385.562937327)
POINT (5630431.5154456 996406.713803432)
POINT (5630424.23433714 996491.317193515)
POINT (5630422.41387709 996512.468022449)
POINT (5630420.59334385 996533.618843946)
POINT (5630418.77273745 996554.769658008)
```

**code**

```
    def executeCreateCopyTableFromFor(self,str):
    query="""
        COPY {table} (
            pointGeometry geometry(point,25832), 
            distanceToNearestEdge Float)
        FROM {str};
    """.format(table=config['Distance_To_Nearest_Edge']['copy_table_name'],str=str)
    print("query: ",query)      
    data = self.connection.execute(query,[])
    print("data: ",data)        
    return data
```

**updat-1**

now for the following query, i receive error:

```
SQL Error [42P01]: FEHLER: Relation »copytabledistancesfrompointstonearestedge« existiert nicht

    COPY copyTableDistancesFromPointsToNearestEdge (
        pointGeometry)
    FROM 'POINT (5630506.13939328 996474.635561104)
POINT (5630504.31893951 996495.786819386)
POINT (5630492.79190135 996473.890690898)
POINT (5630490.97145872 996495.04187886)
POINT (5630479.44442823 996473.145821843)
POINT (5630477.62399676 996494.296939486)
POINT (5630475.80349211 996515.448049693)
POINT (5630464.27655362 996493.552001265)
POINT (5630462.45606011 996514.703041153)
POINT (5630455.17335431 996599.307126336)
POINT (5630453.35249492 996620.458129037)
POINT (5630460.03044341 996387.052104826)
POINT (5630458.21032694 996408.203111568)';
```

Comment: You should split the tasks into: 1) create table, 2) copy points into `pointGeometry` and 3) calculate the distance to the given geometry with an `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

`COPY` does not create tables, so you do not specify the data types in the list of column names.

You have to use `CREATE TABLE` to create the table, then you can fill it with `COPY`.

Comment: so if i want to use copy, then i must remove the data types only..right?

Comment: Yes, that should be right.

Comment: would you please have a look at update-1 section above

Comment: You can copy from a file or from `STDIN`, but you cannot write the `COPY` data as part of the SQL statement. Please read the documentation of `COPY`.

Comment: do you mean that the code in update-1 section above is wrong?!

Comment: Yes, exactly. It has data instead of a file name.